# Dividing a database according to a date in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, splitting, date

[image]I would like to create a new column in my database in order to work with three blocks of observations:
before 2000 (until 1999/12 included), from 2001/01 to 2009/12; from 2010/01 onwards, until today).
Now, I have a column with some dates written in this way: 1999/11/21 00:00:00.000 but I would like just to work with years and month. What can I do?

I think I need first to create a new column with 1999/12 (perhaps using the format "date"?) and then use some functions in order to assign for instance 1 to the period before 2000, the number 2 to the period between 2001/01 to 2009/12, and 3 to the other.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Which kind of database / datasource are you referring to?

Comment: What field type are we talking about?

Comment: 1999/11/21 00:00:00.000 belongs to a column those type is QdateTimem and Typename xsddateTime.

Comment: I am working with the installation date of some urban features

Answer (score 3):

A QGIS way (independent from the datasource / database) would be to calculate a new column using the `Field Calculator` and using a `CASE STATEMENT` on the `QdateTimem` column (or how your column is called):

```
CASE
    WHEN "QdateTimem" IS NULL THEN 'E'
    WHEN "QdateTimem" <  make_datetime( 1999,12,31,23,59,59) THEN 'A'
    WHEN "QdateTimem" <  make_datetime( 2010,12,31,23,59,59) THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
END
```

This will create a new column like:
[image]

Comment: This really works? Because everything fulfilling your first WHEN also fulfills the second WHEN.

Comment: Thank you. I have two doubts: first, where should I put this expression? Second, for B, should not been "between"? Thanks!

Comment: @Erik Multiple `if` would cause an issue, but `WHEN` finds the first criteria, so yeah, I'd expect that to work. Fewer comparisons makes it faster

Comment: You need to open the field calculator have a look here: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#using-the-field-calculator @Erik - the case statement jumps out of the first criteria it fulfills, so writing it chronological is needed (or you include an extra "and")

Comment: I added a screenshot. I called the column where I have the data "anno". it is a date field.

Comment: @Geo_it maybe you need to update your QGIS, I don't know which version brought us make_datetime.

Comment: I downloaded a new version, now I can use the make_datetime function. Now it works! Just one more question. If there are some empty cells, how do I deal with that? can I assign another letter to them?

Comment: I have updated the answer for the `IS NULL`  case. If my answer helped you please accept it :-) (checkmark), thank you!